# Parse.com(Android) - How to clean a ParseUser after update the app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an app in PlayStore with FacebookLogin, but I want to work just with AnonymousUser from now.

Since the app keeps the currentUser after a update, I would like to know how to clean this one and set an anonymousUser after someone update the app to a new version.

I don't mind to lose the data already save for that users.

Answer (score 1):

The ParseUser object has an isAuthenticated() method, this might be what you are looking for.

On app startup check if ParseUser.getCurrentUser().isAuthenticated() and sign out if it is